# Drawing a outline around card edges by using OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv, camera

Currently i am trying to read a square card by using an OCR engine. But before processing image, i want during capturing card image, user should only capture card not other surrounding noise. So for that i looked for overlay & able to create a overlay on camera screen but it is not that useful. So right now i am looking forward some help, how to draw a contour / a outline around a square card when user see it in camera eye as this example.

for ex. [image]

Any body has done this before ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Try to be more specific

Comment: See [this related question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/finding-squares-in-image) (with a wealth of answers) on dsp.stackexchange.com - you might want to try there instead of on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

At first use [cvCanny](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_feature_detection.html) to detect all contours on your image.

Then you can use [Standard Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) for detection of all lines on the image.

Then you can calculate their intersections and find 4 points: the leftmost and the rightmost of the top and the bottom of the image. 
You can ignore small lines which are on the the left and right borders of the image by changing the property of threshold.